# red-green color blindness compatible vim theme

Tags: vim, colors

I am looking for a vim theme accessible to users with red green color blindness. In particular, the red text on a dark terminal background all but disappears. Do any of you know of a good theme? Or have resources useful for designing one?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am not colorblind so I don't really know what works and what doesn't. I use the [desert](http://hans.fugal.net/vim/colors/desert.html) color scheme which works great for me, but your best guess would be to go to http://code.google.com/p/vimcolorschemetest/ and just check them all out.

Answer (score 4):

In my .vimrc I added:

```
set background=dark
```

That helped a lot.

Answer (score 3):

https://github.com/romainl/vim-dichromatic

"A dark colorscheme for color blind vimmers"

Answer (score 1):

For anyone that comes accross this post I recommend jellybeans
https://github.com/nanotech/jellybeans.vim

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).